# Bootstrap-Vue Form Datepicker's dropdown calendar misshaped issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

Imported the sample code from [Bootstrap components](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-datepicker/), then it shows a mistaken view of calendar below.
[image]

In main.js, I imported Bootstrap-vue as below.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './assets/scss/app.scss'
import { BootstrapVue, BootstrapVueIcons } from 'bootstrap-vue'



Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.use(BootstrapVueIcons);

Vue.config.productionTip = true;

let app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      render: h => h(App)
    });
```

In a component, I included Form datepicker as below.

```
<template>
    <div class="form-container">
        <section id="search">
            <div>
                <label for="example-datepicker">Choose a date</label>
                <b-form-datepicker id="example-datepicker" v-model="value" class="mb-2"></b-form-datepicker>
                <p>Value: '{{ value }}'</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: maybe you have global css selectors that overrideing datepicker styles ?
try to import it to new project with no custom styles, does it works ?

Comment: Nothing has changed, though.

Comment: please check [this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-grothendieck-mo7oo) it seems to be working fine with no errors, have you imported both css files ?

Comment: I'm using a custom SCSS and importing scss files from the bootstrap-vue package. Thanks to your Demo, it seems scss file is not working when applying form-datepicker module.

Comment: maybe you've added custom css that made datepicker classes not working

Comment: I'm using third-party css package from npm. That might be the reason why.